# Helping functor environnement oz?

Tags: parsing, functor, oz, mozart

I got a parse error on the line 240 which is:   GUI_port={GUI.portWindow}.
 I don't understand everything was getting well before. Can someone help me, there is not any other problem for compiling.

```
functor
import
   GUI at 'GUI.ozf'
   Input at 'Input.ozf'
   PlayerManager at 'PlayerManager.ozf'
   Browser   
define
   GUI_port
   BomberList
   Maping
  .....
in
  GUI_port={GUI.portWindow}
   {Send GUI_port buildWindow}
   BomberList={Begin Input.bombers Input.colorsBombers  1}
   Maping={BeginPlayer BomberList  map(people:nil listb:nil ports:nil listbonus:nil m:Input.map )}
  {RunGame BomberList Maping}
end
```